# Info AES cryptanalysis

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, reference-request

I have some doubts regarding AES weakness and AES cryptanalysis. While it is relatively simple to find Cryptanalysis info on previous ciphers, I get confused about understanding various types of Cryptanalysis attacks on AES.

So far, for example, I've found that AES's weakness could be in its algebraic structure. Anyone knows good references where  I can find more precise info on AES cryptanalysis (i.e. the  MITM attack/Biclique attack) or could anyone briefly explain to me the main attacks on AES?

For Side-channel attacks, are we basically referring to attacks on the implementation of AES? Could anyone suggest to me any public source for more info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many resources, including here on attacks on AES, which is a vast subject. Here are some pointers.

Summary: There are no noteworthy attacks on the full AES. Some attacks with gain over brute force complexity on vastly reduced round variants exist.

*Yet Another Algebraic Cryptanalysis of Small Scale Variants of AES*: https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/695

[side channel attacks on AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19525/side-channel-attacks-on-aes)

Here is a thesis from Bergen university with an overview that may be a good place to start.

https://bora.uib.no/bora-xmlui/bitstream/handle/1956/23333/CryptanalysisOfAES4.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y

[Does AES-NI offer better side-channel protection compared to AES in software?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43563/does-aes-ni-offer-better-side-channel-protection-compared-to-aes-in-software)

[Is AES without T-Tables nor S-Box resistant to side-channel?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81547/is-aes-without-t-tables-nor-s-box-resistant-to-side-channel)